# Did Naruto and Sasuke receive the Sage of Six Path's chakra or Asura's and Indra's chakra?

Tags: naruto

So Naruto already has Asura's chakra, and Sasuke has Indra's chakra. 
Did the Sage of Six Paths give them his own chakra? 
Or did he give Indra's chakra to Naruto and Asura's chakra to Sasuke which fused together to make his own?

Answer (score 4):

The Wiki only states that Hagoromo gave Naruto [Six Paths Yang Power](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Six_Paths_Yang_Power) and gave Sasuke [Six Paths Yin Power](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Six_Paths_Yin_Power). That's not the chakra specifically, but rather a technique. Although there was some chakra transference involved.

Hamura, Hagoromo's brother, only had Six Paths Yin Power and Hagoromo's children didn't have either.
Indra had Yin Release and Asura had Yang release but they didn't have anything like the power given by Hagoromo to Naruto and Sasuke. I know you didn't claim that Asura and Indra had these powers but I'm just stating that these two powers Naruto and Sasuke received aren't in the same context as their reincarnated power. Hagoromo did give these powers to them because they are Asura and Indra reincarnated but the power didn't develop in them because of this, it was given to them whole by Hagoromo.

The "fusing" of chakra you mentioned was only demonstrated in Sasuke's left EMS turning into a Rinnegan, but I'm not sure if was blending of chakra or simply because he received half Hagoromo's power, so he gets half of his eyes turned into Rinnegan. This last part is highly speculative, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no they had the power hagoramo otsutsuki(sage of six paths)just helped them tap into it.they had the power because hashirama senju and madara uchiha were reincarnation of idura and ashura and naruto and sauske are hashirama and madaras descendants that happend to unlock it so in a way the sage and idura and ashuras chakra played some part

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood the Six Paths powers is that Hagoromo stirred up Indra and Ashura's chakra's and brought them to the forefront, strengthening the powers Naruto and Sasuke already had (evidenced by Sasuke's improved Susanoo that could be summoned in an instant, no stage-by-stage advancement needed, and Naruto's improved-to-ridiculous physical strength).

Then he gave them both the full powers Indra and Ashura had the potential for, Six Path Sage Mode for Naruto and the unique Rinnegan of Sasuke, like he gave Ashura the SPSM previously because it was what he had the capacity for but he didn't do the same for Indra, which was what caused the rift between them.

Then finally on top of that, Hagoromo gave them the Yin and Yang seals and all the linked abilities (like Naruto's instant healing power and the Rikudo: Chibaku Tensei seal).

That's my understanding of it.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is "yes."

The fact remains that, as the sage said, both Asura's and Indra's chakras were gifted to them by the sage. I'm not sure which episode this was, but right before the final confrontation between Naruto and Sasuke, Hangomoro states something along the lines of "originally I gave one (Asura) all the power and they had conflict. This time I gave both of them equal power, and there is still conflict," pleading for Naruto to finally resolve the confrontation between the reincarnations of the brothers.

Comment: so Naruto and Sasuke got the chakra of the other 2 halves?

Comment: If you mean the other two halves as in Asura and Indra, then yes, they got a variation of that chakra, but it was suited specifically for them. Naruto got a little chakra from all of the bijuu (controlling the bijuu was a specialty of the Senju clan who decended from Asura), and Sasuke was granted the advanced mangekyo sharingan (variation of the sharingan which was descended from Indra).

Comment: and then six paths gave Naruto a bit of Indra's chakra to fuse with his own and give him the sage's truth seeking balls and levitation and he gave Sasuke a bit of Ashura's chakra to fuse with his own to give him the sage's eyes(rinnegan)..right?